# Плагин Google's website translator

Tags: javascript, плагин, google-translate

Доброго времени суток

Я использую `Google Translate API` и, хотел бы еще в самом начале загрузки страницы, задать определенный язык перевода. Так сказать: неродной, - но по умолчанию.
Как мне организовать подобный запрос?

За ранее спасибо за уделенную мне минутку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого необходимо перед загрузкой страницы установить куку googtrans в нужное значение.

```
setcookie('googtrans', '/en/ru');
```

Если не подходит, то есть и [другой вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773687/google-translate-set-default-language).

Comment: Большое спасибо, выручил.